# Seeking help on syntax error with js string concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle between the `innerHTML` of a table data cell from an AJAX output from `onclick` row event:

JS:

```
    ...
    var thisrownumber = 0;
    var detailednote = '';
    var simplifiednote = '';
    htmlStr += '<table>';
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        thisrownumber ++;
        detailednote = v.note_ids;
        simplifiednote = '<img class="See" src="~.png" alt="See" style="width:20px; height:20px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;See';
        htmlStr += '<tr onclick="shrow(' + thisrownumber + ',' + detailednote + ',' + simplifiednote + ')">'
                + '<td>' + v.date + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + v.r + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + v.f + ': ' + v.s + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + '<span id="span_note' + thisrownumber + '">' + simplifiednote + '</span>'
                + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
    });
    htmlStr += '</table>';
    $("#content").html(htmlStr); 
} // function close

function shrow(x,y,z){
        var lang3 = "span_note";
        var shrow = x;
        var span_note = lang3.concat(x);
        if(document.getElementById(span_note).innerHTML == y){
            document.getElementById(span_note).innerHTML = z;
        }
        if(document.getElementById(span_note).innerHTML == z){
            document.getElementById(span_note).innerHTML = y;
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Getting error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: does it tell you a line number? And are you sure the offending code has been posted above?

Comment: line number 1 of my PHP page referencing this JS page ... outputting this as well: See Notes)">  See Notes)">  See Notes)">  See Notes)">  See Notes)">

Comment: somewhere you are missing a ) but it's hard to tell, looking at the code sample it's not in the code above...

Comment: The strings need to be escaped (e.g., `,' + detailednote + ',` should be `,"' + detailednote + '",`), but I don't think that's your issue, because that would throw a different error.